# How do I count how many users indicated one, two, three or four answers in an survey?

Tags: python, pandas, count, multiple-columns

I have this survey dataset and I would like to indicate the preferences of users. The Dataset looks like this:

```
User      Men     Women     Non-bi     Asexual 

1         Men     Women     
2         Men 
3                 Women     Non-bi 
4                                      Asexual
```

I would like to be able to count how many users prefer men, women, non-bi people or an combination of it. Is there an easy way in python to count such data and give statistics?

One idea would be to convert all answers into a list or into one column and then I could count the instances of the different combinations.

Comment: you have this data in csv file? have you loaded this to a pandas dataframe?

Comment: How looks expected ouput?

Answer (score 0):

You can maybe use:

```
target = ['Men', 'Women', 'Non-bi']

# get rid of non relevant column
tmp = df.drop(columns='User').notna()

# keep users having at least one target
m1 = tmp[target].any(axis=1)
# drop rows having another match
m2 = ~tmp.drop(columns=target).any(axis=1)

# count
count = (m1&m2).sum()
```

Output: `3`

Answer (score 0):

If need count all combinations of answers convert rows to `frozenset`s with remove missing values and use [`Series.value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
s = df.set_index('User').apply(lambda x: frozenset(x.dropna()), axis=1).value_counts()
print (s)
(Asexual)          1
(Women, Non-bi)    1
(Men)              1
(Women, Men)       1
dtype: int64
```

Or reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) with convert to `frozenset`s:

```
s = df.set_index('User').stack().groupby('User').agg(frozenset).value_counts()
print (s)
(Asexual)          1
(Women, Non-bi)    1
(Men)              1
(Women, Men)       1
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Or if need match values by list - each row is count only once use [`DataFrame.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html), gtet at least one `True` by [`Series.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) and count boolean by `sum`:

```
need = ['Men', 'Women', 'Non-bi']

out = df.isin(need).any(axis=1).sum()
print (out)
3
```

---

```
need = ['Men', 'Women', 'Non-bi']

out = df.reindex(need, axis=1).isin(need).any(axis=1).sum()
print (out)
3
```